# Getting type from previous template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

How can I achieve something like this:

```
//where Low's parameter is of a type of Range's first parameter  
Range<char,Low<5>> range;
```

The problem here I see that I would want/like the type Low to have their parameter dependent on Range's first parameter, so for example:

```
template<class IntType,class LowType>
struct Range
{
};
```

and having:

```
template<class T>//how to do it that this parameter is of a type of Ranges first parameter?
struct Low
{
};
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You are confusing type and non-type arguments. It's hard to tell what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Partial specialization will do the job for you:

```
template<class IntType, class LowType>
struct Range;
                               //vvvvv
template<class IntType, template<class, IntType> class LowType, IntType N>
struct Range< IntType, LowType<IntType, N> >{
                             //^^^^^^^
  // implementation here
};
```

**Edit**
It works with some changes shown above, but you need to change your `Low` struct template:

```
template<class IntType, IntType N>
struct Low{
};
```

And use it like shown [here on Ideone](http://ideone.com/ljACe). But then the question arises: why do you need an extra `Low` struct? Wouldn't the following suffice?

```
template<class IntType, IntType Low>
struct Range;
```

And if you really need that `Low` struct, you could always do the following (using the `Low` struct shown above):

```
template<class IntType, IntType LowNum>
struct Range{
  typedef Low<IntType,LowNum> LowType;
  // ...
};
```

And use it like `Range<int,5>`, making the use of `Range` way more convenient for the user while still using the `Low` struct internally.

Comment: apart from a typo in your first dcl (not a problem at all) there is a problem that it doesn't compile, and second problem is as you see in my example I would like to not to have specify third param.

Comment: @There: You don't specify a third param, that's what the partial specialization is for. I'm looking into the other problem.

Comment: I think it would "work" if it looked like this: http://ideone.com/nwILC. But then again, if you have a `template <int> struct Low;` then you can't magically turn it into a `template <char> struct Low;`.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not convinced I understand your aim correctly, I post this just
in case this can be some hint for you.
If some modifications are allowed, the following setup might meet the purpose:

```
template< class T, T V > struct Low {
  typedef T underlying_type;
};

template< class T > struct Range {
  typedef typename T::underlying_type value_type; // example
};

Range< Low<char,5> > range;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `Range` class template should be written as,

```
template<class IntType, template<int N> class LowType>
struct Range          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ note this!
{
};
```

And define `Low` class template as,

```
template<int N>  //note the difference!
struct Low
{
};
```

NOTE: `Low` class template takes an integer constant *value*, not *type*, as argument!

Comment: @Nawaz and what if I have Range<long long,Low<5>>?

Comment: @Nawaz Yes it will but it's not the only point. I would also like to have it space efficient ;).

Comment: @Nawaz and it will only work for numbers from int range not long long and this is bit of a problem.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: Make the type `long long`. And that is not a problem if you do so.

Comment: @Nawaz it is a problem if first param of Range will be char. Then max is 127 and min -127, absolutely no chance to go ever over this with long long (it is just to "long", pun intended)